# What code should .htaccess of files directory hold in drupal 7.25?

Tags: security

The module [Security Review](https://drupal.org/project/security_review) gives the report my `.htaccess` in files directory is a security risk because says it has insufficient code to protect the site from anyone wanting to make php edits. However, have checked it with drupal org docs and I can see the .htaccess in files directory matches up with correct security script to keep out any such attempts.

Anyway I am trying to ascertain correct code input for .htaccess in the files directory. I remember there was a bug with this so maybe the security module is picking it up, I don't know.

```
# Turn off all options we don't need.
Options None
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Set the catch-all handler to prevent scripts from being executed.
SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
<Files *>
# Override the handler again if we're run later in the evaluation list.
SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2013_003
</Files>

# If we know how to do it safely, disable the PHP engine entirely.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_flag engine off
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.htaccess` you show is correct - it is actually the default `.htaccess` that Drupal versions above 7.24 (including the current 7.28) will generate for the files directory if the `.htaccess` file is missing.

In other words, the warning you get from [Security Review](https://drupal.org/project/security_review) is a false postive. There is no malicious alteration.

Your issue is a known bug with Security Review that has already been raised in the module's issue queue at Drupal.org. There is a also a patch that is supposed to fix this issue in the [module's issue queue](https://drupal.org/node/2141217).

You may help the community by applying and reviewing this patch.